# how do i remove a string from another string in c# unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two strings (text) and (a). I want to remove (a) from (text) after an if statement
this is what I have

```
public string text; 
public string a = 'a';

void Update(){
     if(text.Contains('a')){
        text - a;
     }
}
```

but I get error with this that I cannot use - how do I remove it

Comment: google string.replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is using the string.Replace

```
string text = "This is my text";
string a = "i";
text = text.Replace(a, "");
```

'text' will be: Ths s my text

Comment: Just to add: In order to remove you would rather simply do `text.Replace("a", "");` .. I think that would be the thing OP actually looks for and not some random example ;)

Comment: @derHugo I updated the example ;)